# How can I use Django's update_or_create function for a model with multiple fields?

Tags: django, model

I have a model with many fields. In order to update my model, I make a query for my DB and using the dictfetchall() from Django I get a list of dicts containing the results from the query (each key in each dict is the column name for 1 object).

```
class Enterprise(models.Model):
    --- primary key here ---
    ...
    --- many other fields here ---
```

I want to use the Django's function [update_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) for updating the existing rows with new information or creating new rows if the object already not exists (based on its pk).

But I don't know how to implement this, due to the large number of fields. Furthermore, the dict keys are not equal to the name of the field in my model.

How can I do this?

Than you!

Answer (score 0):

If I simplify the question a little, you have a list of many objects as dicts you and to add to your database. Some are new, and some already exist. You want to update the existing and create the new ones.

You can use `django-bulk-update-or-create` to do that.

For the example, I'll use `inputs` as the list of dictionaries containing your new information.

```
Enterprise.objects.bulk_update_or_create([
    Enterprise(**fields)
    for fields in input
], ["all_your_fields_here"], match_field="pk")
```